# Type Error: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body - in asp.net core with swagger UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have run my swagger API, but I got the issue into swagger UI. This is my Controller.

```
[Route("office/[controller]")]
public class AttendeeController : BoxOfficeControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public DataActionResponse<IList<AttendeeDetailModel>> GetAll(TicketingModes eventType, int? showId = null)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image]
So, What am I doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi @Kumavat vijay, please share enough code to reproduce the issue. What is your `DataActionResponse` and `BoxOfficeControllerBase`? Are `AttendeeDetailModel` and `TicketingModes`  simple models?

Answer (score 0):

> So, What am I doing wrong, and how to fix it?

You did not declare how your parameters are supposed to be handled.

```
[HttpGet]
public DataActionResponse<IList<AttendeeDetailModel>> GetAll([FromQuery]TicketingModes eventType, [FromQuery]int? showId = null)
```

It seems that `TicketingModes` is a complex type (class probably), which means the framework will try to read it from the request body by default (as if you had set [FromBody]).

However, GET requests do not have a body. You need to find another way. Pass it as query parameters if it's small, or pass it in the body but use a different HTTP verb.